# How to get inputs value using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My script fetchs and insert some data from db and displays to the user then I decied to slightly change my code and add some functionality.For example what if any of textbox is empty so that I have added a java script file that controls this sitituation.Bu I cant get the value of textboxes values from index .php file

this is index.php file

```
<?php    
$records = array();
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "app");   
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $first = $_POST["first"];
    $last = $_POST["last"];
    $bio = $_POST["bio"];    
    $insert = $db->prepare("Insert into people (first,last,bio,created) values(?,?,?,NOW())");
    $insert->bind_param("sss", $first, $last, $bio);
    if ($insert->execute()) {
        header("location: index.php");
    }    
}
if ($result = $db->query("select * from people")) {    
    if ($result->num_rows) {    
        while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $records[] = $row;
        }
        $result->free();    
    }    
} else {
    $db->error;
}    
?>    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sites.js"></script>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>    
<?php
if (!count($records)) {
    echo "no";
} else {
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First</td>
            <td>Last</td>
            <td>Bio</td>
            <td>Created</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        foreach ($records as $r) {  
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $r->first; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r->last; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r->bio; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r->created; ?></td>
            </tr>    
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
    <?php
}
?>
```

and this is the html markup

```
<form action="" method="post">
    First <input type="text" id="first"><br>
    last <input type="text" id="last"><br>
    Bio <input type="text" id="bio"><br>
   <button id="submit" value="click me!!"></button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get inputs values from index file like this below But it doesnt work this way It  returns object

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        var name=$('#last');
      alert(name);
    });
});
```

thank in advance

Comment: `var name=$('#last').val()` will work

Comment: Your form elements must have a name/value paring i.e. <input type='text' name='first' value=''> - the id is NOT sent along with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When selecting an element with

```
$('#last')
```

you are getting the entire element in return. With that, you can use the `val()` method to retrieve the elements value:

```
var name = $('#last').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not return the value of name field:

```
var name=$('#last');
```

You can use like:

```
var name=$('#last').val();
```

Also note that, you are missing the name attribute in input fields. Without name attribute you can't get the value in `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the object so you will get the object.

```
var name=$('#last');
```

If you need the value you have to ask for it:

```
var name=$('#last').val();
```